# the meaning of the words "either ... or " in math problems.

Tags: rounding-unit

Use the digits shown on the number cubes below exactly one time each to create a four digit number than can be rounded to either 3,000 or 3,200.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what "rounded to either 3000 or 3200" means, or are you asking about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Regarding the question in your title (your actual "question" seems to be something different, although you never asked a question), there are two kinds of "or" --- inclusive (used in math) and exclusive (often, but not always, used in ordinary language), and in your case the difference does not matter. (I am assuming "rounded to" implies that exactly one of the values is to be chosen.) Sometimes, "either" is used when exclusive "or" is intended, but not always. **(continued)**

Comment: The usual meaning of "either...or" is [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), but that is not likely to be what is meant in this question. Otherwise, 3451 would be an answer: it can be rounded to 3000, but not to 3200.

Comment: Often, the "either ... or" construction is used in order to alert the reader (by the use of "either") that a disjunction (i.e. "or") is involved, in the same way that "both ... and'' alerts the reader (by the use of "both") that a conjunction (i.e. "and") is involved, without the reader having wait until after the first listed object appears to learn whether a disjunction or a conjunction is taking place.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You are asked to use the digits 1,4,5,3 to construct a number that rounds to 3200 (if you round to the 100s) or to 3000 (if you round to the 1000s). This requires the number to be $\geq 3150$ and $< 3250$.